# Tree-Based dimensionality reduction in DNN algorithms

Tags: neural-network, random-forest, feature-selection

My question is straightforward: is it possible to use a tree-based dimensionality reduction such as feature importance embedded in the Random Forest before training the dataset with a DNN algorithm?

In other words, does the use of tree-based feature importance prevents the use of training algorithms different from the tree/Random Forest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read the [DNN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.09039.pdf) article.

Why? Why do you want to use Random Forest before DNN training?

Yes, you can display the feature importance of `random-forest` using

```
random_forest = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42).fit(x_train, y_train)

feature_importances = DataFrame(random_forest.feature_importances_,
                                index = x_train.columns,
                                columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance', 
                                                                 ascending=False)
    
print(feature_importances)
```

But this is a `feature-extraction` method. The DNN is a `neural-network` method.

DNN is more complex than `random-forest`, while `random-forest` handles `feature-extraction`, DNN handles

- `feature-extraction`,
- `back-propagation`,
- `feed-forward` methods.

If you feed enough training samples for DNN, you will have higher accuracy.

- Does the use of tree-based feature importance prevents the use of training algorithms?

No, based on the problem, the sufficient feature size and samples vary. Usually, you don't use `random-forest` to extract 1M images feature importance.

Also, you don't use DNN for small-datasets.